# Vue component not loading the data

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-5.4

I'm testing Laravel 5.4 with Vue Components. But the Problem is Vue Components not displaying in View page.

Here is my Vue File :

**ChatMessage.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>Message text is here</p>
        <small>Author Name</small>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

</script>
<style>
</style>
```

Here is the blade **chat.blade.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chat Rool</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <h1>Chat Room</h1>          
            <chat-message></chat-message>
        </div>
        <script src="js/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my **app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

Vue.component('chat-message', require('./components/ChatMessage.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

There is no error of loading **app.js** Because I have checked it's there in view page.
Can anyone suggest Me what's the wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems in your **ChatMessage.vue**, you just need to export an empty object, as dont have any other properties, like following:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>Message text is here</p>
        <small>Author Name</small>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

Comment: @Hola You can remove the solution from the question, I see you have added this in the question, it will confuse if someone else later looks at this question.

Comment: Right you are, I thought I have checked with that already! 
I have edited..Thanks for the solution though

Comment: @Saurabh Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49664451/how-can-i-add-condition-on-vue-component-that-is-loaded-from-the-view-blade-lara